# Stuck with WMP in C#

Tags: c#, .net, directory, playlist, windows-media-player

I want to fetch 5 media files from a Directory [not with dialog box] and play with axwindowsmediaplayer in C# one after one. Songs to be played as playlist.

I am new to C#.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*
    foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(@"E:\\Project"))
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(info.Name);
    }
    foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles("E:\\Project\\Surprise"))
    {
        FileInfo FileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(FileInfo.Name);   
    }
    */
    string path = @"E:\\Project\\Surprise";
    foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mp4").Select(Path.GetFileName))
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you stuck? We don't "guide" people, we fix specific problems, please show your code and what you are having issues with.

Comment: @RonBeyer above is the code